# How to use ngModel with class data type in angular 2?

Tags: angular, class, angular-ngmodel, two-way-binding

I would like to use class instance for two way data binding in angular 2 project. is it possible?
I shorten code for easy understanding

```
    ---- typescript ----

export class PackageOption {
    name: string;
    description: string;
...
}
import  { PackageOption }  from "./packageoption";
class PackageComponent extends Component implements OnInit {
    ...
    packageOptCurrent: PackageOption;
    ngOnInit() {
        this.packageOptCurrent = new PackageOption();
    }
...
}
    ---- templete ----
       <form [formGroup]="packageOptAddForm" #f="ngForm">
                <input type="text" formControlName="name" name="name" [(ngModel)] = "packageOptCurrent.name">
       </form>
```

I tried but I got this error

ngModel cannot be used to register form controls with a parent formGroup directive.  Try using
          formGroup's partner directive "formControlName" instead.  Example:

```
    <div [formGroup]="myGroup">
      <input formControlName="firstName">
    </div>

    In your class:

this.myGroup = new FormGroup({
   firstName: new FormControl()
});
```

Or, if you'd like to avoid registering this form control, indicate that it's standalone in ngModelOptions:

```
  Example:


<div [formGroup]="myGroup">
   <input formControlName="firstName">
   <input [(ngModel)]="showMoreControls" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: I tried but got error, I edit my question.

Comment: Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem. We can't explain why your code is incorrect without seeing your code.

Comment: Would you please check code again?

Comment: You're mixing reactive forms, where the structure is created by your TS code (form groups and form controls), with template-driven forms, where the structure is created by the template (using ngModel). Don't. Pick one technique.

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible but, you have to declare the instance within the context of the class with component decorator. eg

```
//import typescript person class

@component({
    //some configuration
})
export class SomeClassComponent {
   mPerson = new Person();
}
```